# How to Replace HTTP to HTTPS for page secure

Tags: php, wordpress, http, ssl, https

**error**This Type error Display in this site => why not padlock?
An image with an insecure URL of "http://rotary.mylionsgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/banner.jpg" was loaded on line: 846 of https://rotary.mylionsgroup.com/.
This URL will need to be updated to use a secure URL for your padlock to return.

my site URL given error **not secure** I also use **SSL** Some Page Are Not Secure

Comment: Just change the URL to `https://rotary.mylionsgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/banner.jpg`.

Comment: I will also try BUt it's not one image it all post feature images  ...so How To Deal with manually Please Give Some Reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to your database and some basic confidence with that area try to change all the url of pictures from 'http:*' to 'https:*' - where * is the rest of image url. That's what I always do is I deploy from localhost to production.

Comment: replace all image HTTP to HTTPS But How I Have No Idea

Comment: As I wrote - if you have the access to your database it may be actually simple. Backup database - export it, change all url to the ones containing 'https' - drop database, import again.